# How to retrieve data from mongodb table in php?

Tags: php, mongodb

This is my code in php

```
public function showData(){
    $m = new MongoClient();
    $db = $m->newdb;
    $collection = $db->createCollection("signup");
    $data = $collection->find();
    echo "<pre>";print_r($data);exit;
}
```

but it is returning an empty array while i can see the data in the shell. As we can get the data from mongo shell by writing the command `db.signup.find().forEach(printjson);`

Answer (score 1):

Every time the function runs, it's trying to create a collection that **already exists** (unless you delete it before and this part of your code is a re-creating logic - but then it would really be empty at this point).

You can access it with [selectCollection()](http://php.net/manual/en/mongoclient.selectcollection.php):

```
$collection = $db->selectCollection("signup");
```